# AutoCompleteMode for combobox in c# not available

Tags: c#, wpf, autocomplete, combobox, intellisense

I want my `ComboBox` to be searchable and hence I found that setting the `AutoCompleteMode` property of `ComboBox` does this. But when I try to get that property, `IntelliSense` doesn't show that property. Can someone help me in getting this?

```
<ComboBox
          Grid.Column="3"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Students, Mode=OneWay}"
          SelectedValuePath="ID"
          Name="Combobox"
          DisplayMemberPath="Name"
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedStudentId, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Visibility="{Binding Path=IssuesVisible,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
</ComboBox>
```

In the code-behind file, I tried `Combobox.AutoCompleteMode` but the `IntelliSense` is showing error as I started typing.

Comment: What UI framework are you using? ASP.NET WebForms, ASP.NET MVC, WinForms, WPF...?

Comment: Can you post your code? Maybe you tried `ComboBox.AutoCompleteMode` instead of the name of the instance (For ex: `ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode`).

Comment: I've tried ComboBox1.AutoCompleteMode only but i just found that that property is present in the combobox which is in Syste.Windows.Forms. I am using WPF for this. Is there any other way for making the combobox searchable?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your code and explain what are you using and what have you tried. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) in order to learn how to post questions.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `Combobox` [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.aspx) , there is no such property  as `AutoCompleteMode`. Try [StaysOpenOnEdit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.staysopenonedit.aspx) and [IsEditable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable.aspx)

```
<ComboBox StaysOpenOnEdit="True" IsEditable = "True"  />
```

Comment: On applying the above conditions, i am not able to type anything. I want the typed letters to appear in the combobox and the items should be filtered based on the text entered. Thank you..

Comment: @Laya Try setting `StaysOpenOnEdit = "True"`, by the way, I highly doubt your typed letters will appear. it will only filter though

Comment: It didnt work.. It is just going for conventional search (searching with a single letter)